# Formatting numbers in wolframscript command-line output

Tags: output-formatting, scripting

I am trying to run the following code using wolframscript on windows:

```
a = 123.4567891011213;
Print["a = ",a];
Print["a = ",AccountingForm[a,3]];
```

The output is:

```
a = 123.4567891011213
a = AccountingForm[123.4567891011213, 3]
```

Looks like none of the formatting commands work (e.g. I tried StringForm and it too remains unevaluated). I would just like to format the numbers to be a little shorter. Is it possible?

Comment: It works for me, output is `a = 123.`. What version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.0 for Windows.

Comment: `1.2.0`? Did you mean `12.0`? What does `$Version` evaluate to?

Comment: My Mathematica version is 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019). My Wolframscript version (typing `wolframscript --version` at the command line prompt) is WolframScript 1.2.0 for Windows.

Comment: That is strange. I am on Mac OS, but that should not matter. I see `Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= a = 123.4567891011213;

In[2]:= Print["a = ",a];
a = 123.457

In[3]:= Print["a = ",AccountingForm[a,3]];
a = 123.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s answer to [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208124/wolframscript-command-line-output-from-paralleldo-kernels-contains-lots-of-gibbe/208147#208147) I asked yesterday also solves this problem.

The underlying cause is that default output format is `ScriptForm` and not `OutputForm` as it should be. To manually correct this behavior, it is enough to add `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Later on Wolfram got back to me. They said that upgrading Wolframscript to version 1.3.0 also solves the problem. (This is on Windows. As far as I can tell this was a Windows-only problem).

Comment: It doesn't work in version 1.3.0. However changing the OutputForm seems to be great solution.