# Right syntax to launch multiple kernels on SLURM cluster

Tags: function-construction, parallelization, high-performance-clusters

**Important:**

sometimes you may need to modify the kernel location. In my case I had to find the kernel location explicitly by executing `which wolfram` command in the shell after loading the mathematica module.

Therefore in my case the line below was modified from

`` kernelLaunch = "wolfram -wstp -linkmode connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >&/dev/null &"; ``

to

`` kernelLocation = "/share/apps/mathematica/12.0.0/Scripts/wolfram -wstp -linkmode connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &"; ``

I could only manage to ssh wolfram across nodes when the full kernel location was specified. Again use `which wolfram` to check.

**Original Post**

I have access to a SLURM based cluster where I allocate 2 nodes, each with 12 processors. I am looking for a way to launch all 24 kernels to utilize the resources to the maximum for parallel computation.

```
nodes = ReadList["!scontrol show hostname $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST",String];
cores = ConstantArray[ToExpression@Environment["SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK"], Length@nodes];
dir = Directory[];

Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]];

kernelLaunch = "wolfram -wstp -linkmode connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >&/dev/null &";

HPCKernel[nodes_,cores_]:= MapThread[
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine[#1,"ssh -x -f "<>#1<>" \""<>kernelLaunch<>"\"",#2]]&,
{nodes,cores}];

res = HPCKernel[nodes,cores];
corecount = $KernelCount;

Save["results.wl", {nodes,cores,dir,res,corecount}]
```

In the `results.wl` I get the following outputs:

```
nodes = {"wm8", "wm9"}

cores = {12, 12}

dir = "/work/ah1"

res = {$Failed, $Failed}

corecount = 0
```

We can see that `res` and hence `HPCKernel` has failed to launch any kernel. In fact the `corecount` remains 0. I have success in allocating appropriate resources, however I have no idea how to launch all available kernels. Where am I going wrong with this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always struggle with clusters and I can't give you a full solution, but I'll share the setup code I use on our slurm cluster. Perhaps you can adapt it. It works even when you get a different number of cores on each node. I added some comments to it.

This solution assumes that you set up things so that you can run arbitrary commands on any node using `ssh nodename command`. I set up passwordless authentication for this. I am certain that there are much better ways with slurm, but this works, and I did not have more time to spend on it.

```
(* This is SlurmSetup.m, placed in $UserBaseDirectory/Applications. 
   It is the first thing I load in every script meant to run on the cluster. *)

If[
    Environment["SLURMD_NODENAME"] === $Failed,
    Print["NOT RUNNING IN A SLURM JOB!  ABORTING!!"];
    Abort[]
]

Begin["SlurmSetup`"]

(* Have decent printing from subkernels, 
   see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208124/12 *)
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]

Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];

(* I used this when I needed M12.0 but it wasn't the default version. Thus I needed to launch kernels with math1200. *)
(*$RemoteCommand = "ssh -x -f -l `3` `1` -a math1200 -wstp -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit -nopaclet";*)

(* Parse SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE to find out how many tasks we can launch on each node. 
   Look up the syntax in the slurm docs. It's tricky. *)
tasksPerNode =
  StringSplit[Environment["SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE"], ","] //
    Map[StringCases[{a : (DigitCharacter ..) ~~ "(x" ~~ b : (DigitCharacter ..) ~~ ")" :> ConstantArray @@ FromDigits /@ {a, b}, 
                     a : (DigitCharacter ..) :> FromDigits[a]}]] //
    Flatten;    

headNode = Environment["SLURMD_NODENAME"];

nodes = ReadList["!scontrol show hostname $SLURM_NODELIST", String];

(* Set up the correct number of subkernels on each nodes that slurm allocated for us. 
   These will be automatically launched by LaunchKernels[] *)
$ConfiguredKernels = MapThread[RemoteMachine, {nodes, tasksPerNode}];

Print["Parallel run information: "]
Print[{tasksPerNode, headNode, nodes, $ConfiguredKernels}]
Print[""]

(* Subkernels don't load Kernel/init.m, so I have an alternative init files that sets up $Path and other things. I load at here for the subkernels. *)
(* ParallelNeeds["MyInit`"] *)

(* Increase timeout because on our cluster kernel launching tends to time out ... *)
Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 30.;

(* I print this for diagnostic purposes ... sometimes people hog the licenses. *)
Print["Available process licenses: " <> IntegerString[$MaxLicenseProcesses - $LicenseProcesses] <> "."]
Print["Available subprocess licenses: " <> IntegerString[$MaxLicenseSubprocesses - $LicenseSubprocesses] <> "."]

Print["Launching " <> IntegerString@Total[tasksPerNode] <>  " kernels..."]
LaunchKernels[] (* use only LaunchKernels[], never LaunchKernels[n] *)
Print["Finished launching " <> IntegerString@Length@Kernels[] <> " kernels."]

Print[""]

End[]
```

Comment: thanks. I am going to take a look at your code and give this a try.

Comment: the kernel count is again 0. Do you think that is because i should have more than 1 tasksPerNode to launch any kernel on both machines? Is this the issue?

Comment: also, from your answer: "This solution assumes that you set up things so that you can run arbitrary commands on any node using ssh nodename command. I set up passwordless authentication for this."  can you please let me know how do i ensure that i have this pre-requisite of passwordless authentication? does this mean that mathematica sessions should be loaded on both nodes and that if i am on one node i should be able to do ssh nameofothernode math - script filename.m to run some file on the other node. Sorry but i am new to clusters and have no idea how to proceed with this.

Comment: I'm not terribly experienced with clusters either. Are you sure you requested more than 1 task per node in the job file?

Comment: I *think* with Mathematica you want 1 CPU/task because every subkernel uses 1 core and each subkernel is counted as one task.

Comment: Available process licenses: <>IntegerString[Infinity]<>.
Available subprocess licenses: <>IntegerString[Infinity]<>.
Launching 2 kernels...
bash: wolfram: command not found

SubKernels::timekernels: Timeout for subkernels. Received only 0 of 1 connections.
bash: wolfram: command not found

SubKernels::timekernels: Timeout for subkernels. Received only 0 of 1 connections.
Finished launching 0 kernels.

Comment: As for the ssh thing, google for "public key authentication ssh" or similar to see how to set it up.

Comment: looking back at your script I did not understand: `(* Subkernels don't load Kernel/init.m, so I have an alternative init files that sets up $Path and other things. I load at here for the subkernels. *)`  Can you please provide a template of such a file? I fear this is maybe the reason the script has not worked for me yet.

Comment: @AliHashmi Subkernels don't load any initialization file. If you have a `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` file, it won't be loaded on subkernels. I simply create a package, put it in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`, and load it explicitly using `Needs` and `ParallelNeeds`.