# Is it possible to do grid like printing on commandline when executing scripts on Ubuntu?

Tags: scripting, printing, command-line

I am executing scripts on command line (cli) using `wolfram -script code.m`. However I couldn't find a solution that can print data in a grid like or fixed-width manner. Eg. with the following in `code.m`

```
Grid[{{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7}}]
```

the cli outputs nothing instead of

```
1   2
3   4   5
6   7
```

1. How to achieve this?

**Env**
OS: Ubuntu

Comment: On Windows, with wolframscript.exe, I get the output you want.

Comment: @flinty that's strange I wouldn't have expected there to be a difference based on OS...in ubuntu both `wolfram` and `wolframscript` yield the same 'nothing' output...do stick to `wolfram` though

Comment: Ah right, that's interactive, if I add `-script` to wolframscript (there is no wolfram.exe on my path) then I get no output. Adding `-print all` doesn't help.

Comment: This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208123/formatting-numbers-in-wolframscript-command-line-output) can probably help.

Comment: @Syed thnx ...however using `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]` has no effect on the cli output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on windows v12.2.0, but it is a bit of a hack as you can see. Perhaps try this and it will work on Linux as well. If not let me know and I will delete this answer.

```
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]

alist={{1,2}, {3,4,5},{6,7}}
Print["First attempt"]
Grid[alist]

Print["TableForm output"];
t = alist //Grid
Print[t]
```

[image]

Comment: `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]; Print@Grid@list` works! thnx...I'll accept post few more answers